# YouTube iFrame API on Android (with WebView) - does it have a callback when it fails to build the player?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-webview, youtube-iframe-api

I am building an app that uses the [YouTube iFrame Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Everything works fine when there is Internet connection (the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function gets called correctly). But when I try to load the `.html` that contains the stuff mentioned in [Docs#GettingStarted](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started), `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` never gets called (which I think that is correct), but I do not know which function (nor if there is one) is called notifying that some error occurred.

All in all, which function is called when some error prevents `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` from being called? Is there one?

---

I have just tried to implement the "onError" function, but it also seems to not being called in that situation =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just realized that I was heading the wrong path. This is no YouTube's fault to take at all.

The problem itself is that the **script fails to load**, so that's what we need to track. We can do it by registering an `onerror` callback:

```
// ...

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
tag.onerror = function() {
    // do what you need here. The script failed to load
}

// ...
```